# Twitter Bootstrap Alignment Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I want blog posts to populate the homepage in rows of three. The first three blost posts show up fine, but afterwards the blog posts are off. I would like for each post to line up vertically as well as horizontally. You can see an example [here](http://dev.asterandolivephoto.com/).

Do I need to add a row for every three posts? I'm not sure how I could code that in?

```
<div class="row-fluid">


<?php $cat_id = 10; //the certain category ID
$latest_cat_post = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => rand, 'category__in' => array($cat_id)));
if( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post();  ?>


<div class="span4" style="text-align:center;background-color:#999999;margin-bottom:20px;">

<a class="" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size=0, $attr ); ?></a>
<span><a style="color:#5a5a5a;" class="" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h5 class="lead"><?php the_title(); ?></h5></a>
</span>


</div>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>



</div><!--row-fluid-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override the left margin of your `span4` class.

By adding a `<style>` tag with `margin-left:20px` (or whatever you'd like), the rows align evenly.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/adamdehaven/PP5rn/1/).

Comment: If I add a margin-left:20px (or something similar) they align but then are not centered on the page. Additionally, this will ruin the responsiveness when shrinking the window as well. Any additional ideas?

Comment: You just need to adjust the `CSS` of the page and the Bootstrap defaults for the page you are trying to create. I suggest using the Bootstrap Customizer and reading up on `CSS` guidelines. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Answer (score 0):

The documentation about the [grid system](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) states that:

> The default Bootstrap grid system utilizes 12 columns [...] As this is
>   a 12-column grid, each `.span`* spans a number of those 12 columns,
>   and should always add up to 12 for each row (or the number of columns
>   in the parent).

Meaning that your HTML should more look like:

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="">
    <div class="span4" style="text-align: center; background-color: #999999; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <!-- removed content -->
    </div>
    <div class="span4" style="text-align: center; background-color: #999999; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <!-- removed content -->
    </div>
    <div class="span4" style="text-align: center; background-color: #999999; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <!-- removed content -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid" style="">
    <div class="span4" style="text-align: center; background-color: #999999; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <!-- removed content -->
    </div>
    <div class="span4" style="text-align: center; background-color: #999999; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <!-- removed content -->
    </div>
    <div class="span4" style="text-align: center; background-color: #999999; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <!-- removed content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand this, but how can I call in 9 posts from one category but have the posts be separated every 3 posts into a row? The provided solution works great for static content, but I need to figure out how to call in multiple posts but get every three into a row

Comment: The only rule you have to keep in mind is that the grid system works with 12 columns. So every 3 occurrences in your case (since you want to use `span4`), you have to generate a new `row`.

Comment: right, do you know how to make that happen when using the php that I'm using?

Comment: I am not too familiar with WordPress but I guess something (a bit dirty) like `if($latest_cat_post->current_post % 3 == 0) echo '</div><div class="row-fluid" style="">';` should probably do it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
<?php $cat_id = 10; //the certain category ID

    $latest_cat_post = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => rand, 'category__in' => array($cat_id)));
    if( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post();  
 $open = !($count%3) ? '<div class="threeacross">' : '';
    $close = !($count%3) && $count ? '</div>' : '';
    echo $close.$open;

?>


<div class="span4" style="text-align:center;background-color:#999999;margin-bottom:20px;">

<a class="" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size=0, $attr ); ?></a>
<span><a style="color:#5a5a5a;" class="" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h5 class="lead"><?php the_title(); ?></h5></a>
</span>


</div>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php echo $count ? '</div>' : ''; ?>
```